# upload image on server using post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know i am asking same question but I didn't work on this previously and I am facing problem to upload an image on server using post method. Please help me to solve this issue. I am not understanding how to upload an image on my local server. If I am using bellow code, I am getting an error message:

```
-(void)uploadImageWebService
{  
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8888/emsampleuploads/index.php/api/upload_media/";
// NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImageView.image,90);
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"any_media=%@",[mediaDic objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
long imageSize = postData.length;
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %.2f Mb", (float)imageSize/1024/1024);


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:postData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returnData = %@  returnString=%@",returnData,returnString);
}
```

> Error - ***** Error: logging directory does not exist /Users/atidan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20DC5BB3-7414-4F4D-B9C8-EFCF1A50804C/data/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/

If I am using below code then I am getting a blank dictionary:

```
 -(void)uploadImageWebService
 { 
   NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"any_media=%@",[mediaDic objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];
   NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
   NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@upload_media/",GLOBALURLDOMAIN]]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setHTTPBody:postData];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //  [hud show:YES];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error =nil;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"responsedata =%@",responseData);
     if(error)
     {
         if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
         {
             NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
             NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %ldl %@",(long) httpResponse.statusCode, error);
             return;
         }
         NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
         return;
     }
    if (responseData == NULL) {
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *parsingResultLogin = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"parsingResultLogin = %@",parsingResultLogin);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: first save the image in documents directory get url of image that you copied in documents directory of app this url should be the path along with file name that you use in the call as file path to upload.

Comment: Doesn't AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) have an upload file method ?